# Solution interval of an integral equation

Tags: integration, integral-equations

Suppose $x:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ be continuous function and $x(0)=0$. If $\displaystyle (x(t))^2 \le 2+\int_0^t x(s)\,ds$ for all $t\ge 0$ then which of the following is true?

(A) $x(\sqrt 2)\in [0,2]$.

(B) $x(\sqrt 2)\in [0,3/\sqrt 2]$.

(C) $x(\sqrt 2)\in [5/\sqrt 2,7/\sqrt 2]$.

(D) $x(\sqrt 2)\in [10,\infty]$.

As it is given an inequality we can not differentiate it. How can I proceed to get the proper interval of solution ?

Comment: Type of inequality like Gronwall's inequality comes to mind

Comment: Why cant we differentiate?

Comment: @Rick Because $f\le g$ does not imply $f'\le g'$.

Comment: but we have some conditions, so when is this true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the square root at both sides and then divide by the RHS and multiply by $1/2 $ to obtain

$$  \frac{x(t)}{ 2\sqrt{ 2 + \int _0^t x(t)dt  }}\leq \frac{1}{2}   $$
Therefore,
$$\left (\sqrt{ 2 + \int _0^t x(t)dt }\right )'\leq \frac{1}{2}   $$
so by integrating
$$\sqrt{ 2 + \int _0^t x(t)dt }\leq \frac{t}{2} +\sqrt{2}   $$
Therefore,
$$x(t)\leq \frac{t}{2} +\sqrt{2} \Longrightarrow x(\sqrt2) \leq \frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Also, if you solve 
$$  \frac{x(t)}{ 2\sqrt{ 2 + \int _0^t x(t)dt  }}= \frac{1}{2}   $$
you find that $x(\sqrt{2}) = \frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}$
Therefore, (b) is correct.

Comment: How 2nd inequality follows from first inequality? I'm not getting this!

Comment: @Empty You use the upper bound obtained for $\sqrt{ 2 + \int _0^t x(t)dt } $ here $ x(t)\leq \sqrt{ 2 + \int _0^t x(t)dt }   $, is that what you meant?

Comment: No. I'm saying how $\left (\sqrt{ 2 + \int _0^t x(t)dt }\right )'\leq \frac{1}{2}   $ comes ?

Comment: @Empty oh, this is from the chain rule $$\frac{x(t)}{ 2\sqrt{ 2 + \int _0^t x(t)dt  }}=\left (\sqrt{ 2 + \int _0^t x(t)dt }\right )'$$

Comment: @clark In the 3rd line, how the integrating constant becomes $\sqrt 2$ ?