# Suppose $(x(t))^2 \le 2 + \int_{0}^t x(s)ds$ and $x(0)=0$

Tags: calculus, integration

Suppose $x:[0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ which satisfies $(x(t))^2 \le 2 + \int_{0}^t x(s)ds$ and $x(0)=0$.

Show that $x(\sqrt{2}) \in [0,\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}]$

I applied the leibnitz rule and got $x'(t) = \frac{1}{2}$. Integrating I got $x(t) \le \frac{t}{2} + a$ or $x(t) \le 0$

Now $x(0)=0 $ then $\frac{t}{2}+a = 0$ (In case of equality) and so $a = 0$.

From here the range of $x(\sqrt{2}) \in [0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}]$ but the range given is bigger. Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: How did you get $x'(t) = \frac{1}{2}$? (You cannot differentiate an *inequality*)

Comment: I assumed the equality and differentiated it. Then i got $x(t)= t/2 +a$ now $x(0)=0$ so i am getting $x(t) = t/2$ and the inequality becomes $x(t) \le t/2 $

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solution interval of an integral equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3297095/solution-interval-of-an-integral-equation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X(t)=\int_0^tx(s)ds$. Then the upper bound comes from the differential equation $\dfrac{dX}{dt}=\sqrt{2+X(t)}$, which gives $\sqrt{2+X(t)}= \frac{1}{2}t+\sqrt{2}$, and so $x(\sqrt{2})^2\le (\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2})^2$: that is $x(\sqrt{2})\le \frac{3}{2}\sqrt{2}$. However, this assumes that for the upper bound, the inequality is an equality for all $t$, which is not possible because it isn't true at $t=0$. I think your stricter upper bound also therefore holds.

Comment: Why is $\sqrt{2+X(t)} = \frac{1}{2}t + \sqrt{2}$?

Comment: The negative vote is not from myside. I also didn't understand anything after 'However, this assumes that....'

Comment: I solved the differential equation $\int \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2+X(t)}} dX = \int 1 dt$ to get $2\sqrt{2+X(t)} =t + c$.

Comment: My argument assumes that, for the upper bound, $x(t)^2 = 2 + \int_0^tx(s)ds$, but this can't be true at $t=0$ as LHS = 0, RHS = 2.

Comment: Why does the upper bound come from your equation?

Comment: @mcd How do you calculate the integrating constant $c=\sqrt 2$ ?

Comment: I used $X(0) = 0$.